# Generate "cards" with info in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, copy-paste

I have a sheet for an event and I need to generate identification cards like in the image for the pieces on the contest, around 1000 pieces, so no way to manually do it.

[image]

I did a similar thing years ago but I can't remember how I've done it and can't find the file.

Some kind soul could help me?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: The sheet doesn't have all the fields yet... the image was sent by my collegue.. You can see this one from the other post you've helped me
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JMIBO5QRkN6L9MFry8wWIsEang9PquJX-yxWj7FJ7Wg/edit#gid=1623004240

Answer (score 0):

- first, you will create "template" by copypasting range **A1:L8**
- when done you can deploy your formula after you respectively change ranges:

  ```
  ={{N1,"","","","","","","","","","",""};
  {"","","","","","","","","","","",""};
  {"","CLASSE:","","",N2,"","","N°",N3,"","",""};
  {"","","","","","","","","","","",""};
  {"",N4,"","","","","","","","","",""};
  {"","","","","","","","","","","",""};
  {"","","","","","","","","","","",""};
  {"ESCALA:","",N5,"","","T.ESP.","",N6,"","C/EXP","",O6}}
  ```
- **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LWPHtTvnEhepNYNBsMu37eSXWPMR2UaRDYC5aNYw6s4/edit#gid=820090231&range=A9:L9) - [copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LWPHtTvnEhepNYNBsMu37eSXWPMR2UaRDYC5aNYw6s4/copy)**

  [image: 0]

Comment: There is no other way to do this? To copy and paste and change the cells for around 1000 of this cards is not that effective. Can we do this with a google script or something similar? I really need this automatic as possible

Comment: it could be all done under 15-20min if you would provide all the necessary stuff. also, a lot of it is just me guessing coz of a major lack of your desired output format of the final project

Comment: here I made you already a pre-formatted template for 1000+ cards - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LWPHtTvnEhepNYNBsMu37eSXWPMR2UaRDYC5aNYw6s4/edit#gid=1165307592

Comment: hello, sorry for the delay. I talked yesterday with the organization of the event. They discarted the possibility of doing the labels prior to the event because if someone doesn't attend it will be work thrown to the trash. 

What they want is to print the labels when the people arrive at the place to confirm the registration with a thermic printer or a small label printer, like a "shipping label".

Comment: Can it be done on google docs with a better design template? I think it can be treated like a shipping label because it will be printed 1 by 1 at the moment the person deliver the pieces for the contest